Strange behavior with NextJS 14 cookies
I'm creating a NextJS project and I'm currently being smashed by cookies. I'm new to NextJS 14 since I'm more familiar with getServerSideProps from NextJs 13.
I have this page:
// src/app/dashboard/page.tsx
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import Navbar from "../components/header";
import axios from "axios";

export default async function Dashboard() {
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard");
    console.log(cookies().getAll());
    return (
        <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-black-100">
            {"... some code"}
        </main>
    );
}

I also have this route handler, where I'm trying to set cookies:
// src/app/api/dashboard/route.ts
import axios from "axios";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

interface TokenData {
    access_token: string;
    token_type: string;
    expires_in: number;
}

export async function GET(req: Request) {
    const clientId = process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_ID;
    const clientSecret = process.env.AUTH_SPOTIFY_SECRET;

    try {
        // Request token from Spotify API
        const { data } = await axios.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", null, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            params: {
                grant_type: "client_credentials",
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret,
            },
        });

        const { access_token, expires_in }: TokenData = data;

        const response = NextResponse.json({ message: "Ok", status: 200 });
        response.cookies.set("access_token", access_token, { path: "/" });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: "Failed to fetch access token" });
    }
}

I can't understand why my "access_token" cookie is not being set when I make that axios request in localhost:3000/dashboard. It is only set when I hit localhost:3000/api/dashboard
OBS: I'm using next: v14.2.13, axios: v1.7.7,
